# Publish Cognos Content in Sharepoint 2003

Tags: sharepoint, cognos

What are my options? I'm researching a 3rd party called QueryVision, but would like to explore other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Cognos 8 can integrate with SharePoint 2003 directly.  Check your Administration and Security guide - in recent versions there is a section dedicated to setting this integration up entitled "Deploying Cognos Portlets to Microsoft SharePoint Portal Server 2003 and 2007."

Answer (score 0):

One way you can integrate Cognos content directly into 3rd party portals and apps is to use parameterized URLs.  Here's a link to the best practices document on the IBM site. [Performing Tasks using Parameterized URLs in IBM Cognos 8](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/page123.html)  On page 15, it shows an example of integrating Cognos 8 into Sharepoint.